# How to read a part of a line with DOM?

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm familiar with [PHP's DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) and know how to read special tags of an HTML page.

But now, I want to read a part of a line in a JS File, And I don't know how to do it.

my java script's text is here:

```
  var gblock = '';
  var gblocktitle;
  if(gblocktitle == undefined)
  {
    gblocktitle = 'title';
  }
  gblock += '<div class="g-block">';
  gblock += '<div class="g-block-title">';
  gblock += gblocktitle;
  gblock += '</div>';
  gblock += '<div class="g-poem-block">';
  gblock += '<div class="g-m1">part1</div>';
  gblock += '<div class="g-m2">part2</div>';
  gblock += '<br style="clear:both;" />';
  gblock += '</div>';
  gblock += '<div class="gfooter">';
  gblock += '<div class="gpoet"><a href="#">AAAAAAAA</a></div>';
  gblock += '<br style="clear:both;" />';
  gblock += '</div>';
  grblock += '</div>';
  document.write(gblock);
```

And I want to read `part1` and `part2`

please help me.

Comment: are u trying to read a line  js code ?
like 
  gblock += '<div class="g-m1">part1</div>';

or just 
part1?

Comment: check the answer ,its edited

Comment: @MukulJayaprakash Can I save this alert to an PHP variable?

Comment: what are you trying to achive? the js runs on the browser while php in server, you have to call an ajax function to store it as php varable or as a php session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  var gblock = '';
  var gblocktitle;
  if(gblocktitle == undefined)
  {
    gblocktitle = 'title';
  }
  gblock += '<div class="g-block">';
  gblock += '<div class="g-block-title">';
  gblock += gblocktitle;
  gblock += '</div>';
  gblock += '<div class="g-poem-block">';
  gblock += '<div class="g-m1">part1</div>';
  gblock += '<div class="g-m2">part2</div>';
  gblock += '<br style="clear:both;" />';
  gblock += '</div>';
  gblock += '<div class="gfooter">';
  gblock += '<div class="gpoet"><a href="#">AAAAAAAA</a></div>';
  gblock += '<br style="clear:both;" />';
  gblock += '</div>';
$(gblock).find('.g-m1').html();
alert($(gblock).find('.g-m1').html());
```

try this
U have to use JQuery library..

Comment: This is a `js` question not `php`.

Comment: `OP` stated `my java script's text is here:` top of his question.

Comment: oh ok.. my bad . i looked up on php dom

Comment: No problem, answer in `js` help him if possible.

Comment: :) if this helped you kindly put the answer as correct